# Am I doing a df.Merge wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have one df1 which looks has this row amongst others

```
PlayDate   Timeslot   UserID
2005-09-09   6-16-1   59
```

and I have df2 which contains:

```
UserID   PlayDate   Timeslot   PlayCount   EstProb
59       2005-09-09  6-16-1       1        0.214459
```

I then try and bring in the extra columns from df2 into df1 using a merge.
df1.merge(df2,how='left',on=['Timeslot','PlayDate','UserID'])

(Note that df1 has more columns than exist in df2 hence why I do a left)

When I review df1 afterwards I see:

```
PlayDate    Timeslot   UserID   PlayCount   EstProb
2005-09-09   6-16-1      59       NaN         NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the dtypes of both dataframes.  Make sure that each dtype matches for each column.

Comment: Thanks I literally just thought of that after posting and found that one of the tables had the date formatted as a date and the other as an object. Doh! I used df1["PlayDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["PlayDate"]) to fix.

Comment: Ps. If you post it as an answer I can award you the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure that your dtypes of your dataframes match.

```
df1['PlayDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['PlayDate'])
df2['PlayDAte'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['PlayDate'])
df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on=['Timeslot','PlayDate','UserID'])
```

Output:

```
     PlayDate Timeslot  UserID  PlayCount   EstProb
0  2005-09-09   6-16-1      59          1  0.214459
```